# Concise representative frgament of Swift code

Tags: swift, syntax-highlighting

Recent release of highlight.js syntax highlighter supports Swift and we want to show it off on the home page. I'm looking for a concise representative snippet of Swift code that would fit into the small window here: http://highlightjs.org/. Help? :-)

By "representative" I mean that it should have recognizable traits of the language, like this snippet of C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  /* An annoying "Hello World" example */
  for (auto i = 0; i < 0xFFFF; i++)
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

  char c = '\n';
  unordered_map <string, vector<string> > m;
  m["key"] = "\\\\"; // this is an error

  return -2e3 + 12l;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

@objc class Person: Entity {
  var name: String!
  var age:  Int!

  init(name: String, age: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.age  = age
  }

  // Return a descriptive string for this person
  func description(offset: Int = 0) -> String {
    return "\(name) is \(age + offset) years old"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be correct syntactically to shove `@objc` before `func description()`? (another goal of the snippet is to show off highlighting features)

Comment: No, but you could place it before the class, `@objc class Person`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import Foundation

class DelegateMulticast<T> {

  let delegates = [T]()

  // invokes the given function for each delegate
  func invokeDelegates(invocation: (T) -> ()) {
    for delegate in delegates {
      invocation(delegate)
    }
  }
}
```

It demonstrates the Swift array type syntax `[T]`, generics, function types `(T) -> ()`, the for-in syntax that lacks parentheses, no semicolons ...

Lots of Swift specific stuff

Comment: This one actually uncovered some bugs to fix in the highlighter :-). Thanks! :-)

Comment: @isagalaev cool - glad it helped. Out of interest, have you thoroughly tested the closure syntax? Swift has at least 8 different variations, so could give you a few problems!

Comment: I don't see anything related to closures in https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/swift.js, so it looks like we don't support highlighting those at all. You can contribute that!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ...

```
println("Hello, world")
```

What more could you need? ;-)

Comment: It's not recognizably Swift, is it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var swiftSupported : Bool = true
let ourProduct = "Highlight.js"

if swiftSupported {
    println("\(ourProduct) now supports Swift!")
}
```

Comment: surely `swiftSupported` should be a constant? :-P

Comment: :) Perhaps for marketing purposes... I was thinking more along the lines of this feature being in a new edition.